Immer array concat results in a compiler error
I have a state object like this:
interface IUser {
  name:string;
}
interface ISomething<T> {
  data: { [key:string]: T[]};
}
const state:ISomething<IUser> = { data: { } };

Using immer the following works:
import { produce } from "immer";
const someData:IUser[] = [ {name:"one"}, {name:"two"} ];
state["a"] = [];
const newState = produce(state, (draft => {draft.data["a"].concat(someData);}));
console.log(newState);

Write a function to do the same:
function AConcat<T>(aState: ISomething<T>, items:T[]):ISomething<T>{
  return produce(aState, (draft => {draft.data["a"].concat(items);}));
}

It results with a typescript compiler error at .concat(items):

How could I achieve a concatenation there?

Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.
